# Delphi REST скачать .dat файл с Google Drive

Tags: delphi, файлы, rest, google-drive

Подключаюсь к Google drive api

Хочу скачать оттуда файл с расширением .dat

Картинка jpeg с помощью TMemoryStream скачивается нормально

Запрос строю так

```
RESTResponseDataSetAdapter1.AutoUpdate := false;
  RESTRequest1.Params.Clear;
  RESTRequest1.ClearBody;
  RESTRequest1.Method := rmGET;
  RESTClient1.BaseURL :=
    'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{FileId}?alt=media';
  RESTRequest1.Resource := '';
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddUrlSegment('FileId', FileID);
  try
    RESTRequest1.Execute;
  except
    on e: Exception do
    begin
    Clipboard.AsText := e.Message;
      ShowMessage(e.Message); // Show Exception
    end;
  end;
```

Но для .dat файла на строчке `RESTRequest1.Execute;` выскакивает исключение

*REST request failed: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page*

В чем ошибка?
Как надо скачивать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение

```
RESTResponseDataSetAdapter1.AutoUpdate := false;
  RESTRequest1.Params.Clear;
  RESTRequest1.ClearBody;
  RESTRequest1.Method := rmGET;
  RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{FileId}';
  RESTRequest1.Resource := '';
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddUrlSegment('FileId', FileID);
  try
    RESTRequest1.Execute;
    RESTResponse1.GetSimpleValue('webContentLink', link);
    GetInetFile(link,local_filename);
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Clipboard.AsText := E.Message;
      ShowMessage(E.Message); // Show Exception
    end;
  end;
```

и функция `GetInetFile`

```
function GetInetFile(const fileURL, FileName: string): boolean;
const
  BufferSize = 1024;
var
  hSession, hURL: HInternet;
  Buffer: array[1..BufferSize] of Byte;
  BufferLen: DWORD;
  f: file;
  sAppName: string;
begin
  Result := False;
  sAppName := ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName);
  hSession := InternetOpen(PChar(sAppName),
  INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  try
    hURL := InternetOpenURL(hSession, PChar(fileURL), nil, 0, 0, 0);
    try
      AssignFile(f, FileName);
      Rewrite(f,1);
      repeat
        InternetReadFile(hURL, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BufferLen);
        BlockWrite(f, Buffer, BufferLen);
      until
        BufferLen = 0;
      CloseFile(f);
      Result := True;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(hURL);
    end;
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Проблема была в лишнем параметре `alt=media` в url?

Comment: Zed, Да, и в том, что через TMemoryStream не получается его сохранить в файл, так что я достал его ссылку из Json-реквеста и напрямую скачал

Comment: А без `alt=media` мы просто получаем ответ в формате Json